# Cannot pipe variable to levels

Tags: r, dplyr, levels

I am working with a large data frame and rather than write manipulations to memory, I've been trying to do as much as a I with pipes. In trying to check my factor levels in intermediate steps, I ran into a problem using the `levels` function and wondered if anyone might know what the problem is.

An example:

```
library(dplyr)
Data <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:5],3),
                   y = sample(1:10,length(x), replace=T))
```

The usual way works:

```
levels(Data$x)
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

It mostly works if I use `sapply`:

```
 Data %>% select(x) %>% sapply(levels)
     x  
[1,] "A"
[2,] "B"
[3,] "C"
[4,] "D"
[5,] "E"
```

But piping does not work and returns `NULL`:

```
Data %>% select(x) %>% levels()
NULL
```

Why does `Data %>% select(x) %>% levels()` return `NULL`?

Is there a way to use levels with piped data?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`select` gives a data frame, but `levels` expects a vector as argument, that's why they don't work together; To use `levels` with `pipe`:

You can either use `.$x` to extract the column in the levels method:

```
Data %>% select(x) %>% {levels(.$x)}
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Or a better approach use `pull` instead of `select`, `pull` gives the column as a vector/factor:

```
Data %>% pull(x) %>% levels()
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to pass two variables to levels with either of the above approaches?

Comment: I don't think so. If you have multiple variables, select then lapply like you did should be the correct approach.